# How to filter out outliers from dataset?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

I am trying to filter out outliers given a data set (maximum of 50 samples). For example:

dataSet = (10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)

1 and 0.9, and 0.8 should be removed.

Another example:

dataSet2 = (11.0, 10.0, 8.0, 6.0, 1.0);

1.0 should be removed.

Can somebody recommend what type of formula/statistics should I be using to determine the outliers?

Comment: Please don't post the same question again, after it got closed. Read the Cross Validated guidelines [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and if you consider your question on-topic, amend the original question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback, this is not the same question as before as it does not ask about programming compared to my first question. But I should have amend the original question

Comment: It is not clear why certain values should be removed in your case. I think the question lacks some important information to be understood.